# How to display the contents of a table in a database in form of string in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

This is what I have tried. I displayed the results in form of a table. I want the results to display like a single line for which I can apply a marquee. My instructor advised to put the results in a string and then display them. How to implement that?

```
<?    
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "qwerty") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("ups_status") or die(mysql_error());

$value = $_POST[input] ;
$order3 = "SELECT * FROM ups_status1 WHERE (ups_temp > 45)and(Ipaddress LIKE '%".$value."%')";
$results3 = mysql_query($order3) or die('Invalid query: ' .mysql_error());

echo"<div id=ups_sty ><h4>Temperature Status</h4></div>";
if(mysql_num_rows($results3)>0)
{
echo "<div id=ups_sty2><marquee behavior=alternate>Temperature of one or more UPS is high!!</marquee></div>";   
echo "<table border='0' width='200' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2'>";

echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#002C40' style='color:#FFF'>
<td height='35px' width='500px'>IP ADDRESS</td> 
</tr>"; 

  while($result5 = mysql_fetch_row($results3))
 {
   echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>
<td height='25px'>".$result5[1]."</td>
</tr>" ;
 }
echo "</table>";
/*Instead of displaying them in a tabular way, I want to display them consecutively...*/
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this(Complete Code)

```
?>
<div id=ups_sty2>
    <marquee behavior=alternate>Temperature of one or more UPS is high!!</marquee>
</div> 

    <?php
        while ($raw = mysql_fetch_array($results3))
            {
                <p><?php echo $raw["tbale_field name1"]; ?></p>
            }
    ?>
```

Comment: The result is still coming in form of a table. I want to display the result in the same line. :(

Comment: same line means?? I cant understand. tel me what you exactly need

Comment: can you attach picture of your output

Comment: On displaying the result, all the values should appear consecutively, like in a line horizontally, rather than in a tabular form. Right now it is coming as a single column.

Comment: so you no need table and you need output in single line??

Comment: when you try as above(in your code) is it show as single line??

Comment: Its in tabular form only in my code, which isn't what i want. I want the output in a single line.

Comment: you need to do it with CSS. cz php only gives you data from table

Comment: can we insert the results into a string and display the results?

Comment: ya without table just use while loop with `<p>`.like this `<p><?php echo $raw["tbale_field name1"]; ?></p>`